# camunda on cloud

Tags: php, sql, google-cloud-platform, sdk, camunda

I tried to run camunda on cloud run …it works but on the login page I type demo demo…does not work (failed )
…help me to know where is the right user and password to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Spring Boot build, check which credentials have been defined in application.yml or application.properties.

```
camunda:   
  bpm:
    admin-user:
      id: demo
      password: demo
```